# Como insertar en la base de datos un dato específico con php

Tags: php, html, sql

Tengo una seria duda, tengo una sección donde los administradores, seleccionan opciones de la base de datos y tienen un textarea que es la opción que quiero insertar en la base de datos según el usuario que elijan en el select.

Como haría para que insertara ese texto en el usuario que elijan los administradores? os paso el código que tengo:

```
     <?php session_start();

include_once '../pruebas/conexion.php';

$textarea = $_POST['mi_alerta'];
 $id = $_POST['select_usuario'];

 $sql_editar = "UPDATE usuarios SET alerta='$textarea' WHERE id='$id'";
 $sentencia_editar = $pdo->prepare($sql_editar);
 $sentencia_editar->execute(array($alerta,$id));

    header('Location: reportes_usuario.php');


           <!-- Material form register -->
    <form action="envio_alerta.php" method="POST">
        <p>Nombre</p>
      <select  class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect">
        <option selected>Elige opción</option>
        <?php foreach ($resultado as $dato): ?>
        <option ><?php echo $dato['usuario']?></option> 
        <?php endforeach ?>
      </select>
        <br>
        <br>
      <p>Apellidos</p>
      <select  class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect">
      <option selected>Elige opción</option>
       <?php foreach ($resultado as $dato): ?>
        <option><?php echo $dato['apellidos']?></option>
        <?php endforeach ?>
      </select>
      <br>
      <br>
      <p>Email</p>
      <select name="select_usuario"class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect">
      <option selected>Elige opción</option>
       <?php foreach ($resultado as $dato): ?>
        <option value="<?php $dato['id']?>"><?php echo $dato['email']?></option>
        <?php endforeach ?> 
      </select>
      <br>
      <br>
      <p>Texto</p>
      <div class="form-group z-depth-2">

    <textarea name="mi_alerta" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea3" rows="7"></textarea>
</div>
    </div>

        <div class="text-center py-4 mt-3">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-warning waves-effect z-depth-3" type="submit">Enviar</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: en el option deberias agregar el id del usuario: <option value="<?=$dato['idUsuario']?>"><?php echo $dato['usuario']?></option>

Comment: al hacer el submit recibirias los datos por el post en tu archivo envio_alerta.php

Comment: Puedes detallar como sería el codigo de envio_alerta.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

supongamos el siguiente codigo:

```
<form action="envio_alerta.php" method="POST">
  <p>Nombre</p>
  <select  id="select_usuario" name="select_usuario">
  <option selected>Elige opción</option>
  <?php foreach ($resultado as $dato): ?>
  <option value="<?$dato['id_usuario']"><?php echo $dato['nombre_usuario']?></option> 
  <?php endforeach ?>
  </select>
  <textarea name="alerta" id="mi_textarea"></textarea>
</form>
```

que es la informacion que deseo enviar a (envio_alerta.php), la recibo de la siguiente manera:

```
    <?php
    $id_usuario = $_POST['select_usuario'];
    $textarea = $_POST['mi_textarea'];
    $con = mysqli_connect($server,$user,$clave)or die ("problemas en server");
   mysqli_select_db($basedatos,$con)or die ("problemas con base de datos");

   mysqli_query("UPDATE usuarios set alerta='$textarea' WHERE    id_usuario='$id_usuario'",$con)or die (mysql_error());
echo "Actualizacion correcta";
    ?>
```

de esa forma recibes en el metodo post.Te sugiero leer la documentacion oficial:

[Documentacion](http://php.net/manual/es/tutorial.forms.php)

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80412/discussion-on-answer-by-tegito123-como-insertar-en-la-base-de-datos-un-dato-espe).